# How do you deploy an ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that will need to run on any os. What is the best way to package it so users can install on any os?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your app as self-contained produces a platform-specific executable. The user of your app isn't required to download and install .NET.

[Publish self-contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained)

Please check the official doc about the advantages and disadvantages of publishing self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying an ASP.NET Web API Core application can be done in several ways. Here are a few options:

Deploy ASP.NET Core API application In IIS

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-asp-net-core-api-application-in-iis/

Publish an ASP.NET Core web API to Azure API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-api-management-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Please check based on your requirement.